# Type.GetTypeFromProgID(string) doesnt work on other machine

Tags: c#

```
private bool StartSkript(string Systemskript)
{
    Type typeFromProgID = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("xxx.application"); // this line works on windows 10 and doesnt work on windows server 2019.
    if (typeFromProgID == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    try
    {
        dynamic applicationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeFromProgID);
        applicationInstance.RunFormSkript(Systemskript, 0);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hello,

we are trying to call a function in a running process. The above code finds xxx.application on the dev-machine with no trouble, but in the terminal server test-environment it returns null.

The app xxx is running under the same user as the c# program.

Our first problem is, that we dont really understand why we search for xxx.application (seems to be a class) instead of xxx.exe which would be the processes name.

Next, we dont know how to approach this. How do I check, if I am even looking for the right call "xxx.application"?

Answer (score 1):

ProgID means the ProgramID of a COM-Server. Which is usually registered in the Windows registry after the component was installed.
This is kind of a code to indirectly create an instance of a COM class.

Its kind of an old technique that was heavily used in the 90ties and early 2000 years. ActiveX-Components are based on the COM technology.

Seems the COM-Server with ProgID "xxx.application" is not installed on the terminal server. Or not properly registered. Or your code hasn't enough privileges to read the relevant registry keys etc....